# Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: java, android

I have this error ..

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

**And I get the red code in R.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_list);
    lvBooks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBook);
    ArrayList<Book> aBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, aBooks);
    lvBooks.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

    // Fetch the data remotely
    fetchBooks();
}
```

**Error R:**

[image]

Can anyone help this one?

Comment: Seem you have image resource problem, one (maybe more) of your icons/images have error format, try to remove/fix them then build again.

Comment: How to find damaged image(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

in your gradle(app) file
 in android{ } scope

it will work fine

Answer (score -1):

don't edit(refactor) the extension of file in resource . edit the name but not the extension of that file . if you need to change file extension do it in outside of android studio and bring the new files in that res folder :) thanks